# pre-register app on google play

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-apps, prelaunch

I am working on a product, and have plans to launch in next 4-5 weeks, i have read so many blogs post about a new features of google play console i.e `Pre-Register-App` before launch.so i am also thinking to do the same, i dig google and found many blogs, which explain what is `Pre-registering` , but haven't found any blog that explain, how we can do that, i even dig *Google Play Developer Console* any option for `Pre-registering`. Helping hands will be highly appreciated.

***Blog links***

1). https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fireball&hl=en

2).http://thenextweb.com/apps/2015/05/11/you-can-now-pre-register-for-apps-on-the-google-play-store/#gref

3).http://www.theverge.com/2015/5/10/8581483/pre-register-button-added-to-google-play

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: point us to some place you read about this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After lots of research I can say `Pre-Registration` is open for beta testing. From [this link](http://www.apptamin.com/blog/google-play-beta-testing/)

> **Use Pre-Registration to Build an Instant User Base**
>
> Before you get started with actual beta testing, make sure you
> consider doing a pre-registration campaign. People who sign up will
> get a notification when your app launches.
>
> Imagine having a potential installation base of thousands (or maybe
> even millions) of people, even before your app launches! Here is more
> information on how pre-registration works…
>
> To setup a pre-registration campaign, [contact](https://support.google.com/googleplay/contact/developer_profile_survey/?ctx=game) a Google Business
> Development manager to get things started. You can use your favorite
> user acquisition method like paid ads, social media or your email list
> to drive people to your pre-registration page.
>
> Once you have that setup, it’s time to get back to testing…

Answer (score 4):

> which explain what is Pre-registering

The name is misleading a bit. It's basically notification about application release (so you do not need to bother checking yourself if it is out or not). The main benefit for the publisher is that he can attract the attention for unreleased product so people already know about it when it is out.

At the moment pre-registering feature is not available for every publisher account.

Comment: marcin, how to go about setting this up on play store? Any idea?

Comment: this is not publicly available as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have talked with Google play, this was my question

> How can I make Pre-Register?

This was the answer from google play (chat support).

> I apologize the pre-registration feature is only available as a pilot at this time to a limited number of mobile games.
>
> It means that only selected developers will have the option to use "pre-registration" at this time.
>
> If you are selected to participate, the option will be available in your Console.