# Google Play - How to upload apps as pre-register?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I'm looking for steps that allows me to upload or register apps to be shown on google play as pre-register

As I read in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/50006322/6152553 this feature for limited companies but I'm not sure how for now

Comment: As it says in the answer to the question you link to: To setup a pre-registration campaign, contact a Google Business Development manager to get things started . If you don't have a BD manager fill in the form here to apply for one: https://support.google.com/googleplay/contact/developer_profile_survey/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pre-register app on google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525003/pre-register-app-on-google-play)

Answer (score 0):

You can consult the offial documentation :
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9084187